# SSH to multiple servers [Access denied]

Tags: ssh

I need to write a script to remotely connect from home to my university server via ssh and then from the server terminal, ssh to a virtual machine to process some data. Is this possible?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set login "myuser"
set addr "test.ac.uk"
set addr2 "t002"
set pw "mypassword"

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $login@$addr 
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $login@$addr2 -p 22
expect "$login@$addr2\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
send "cd /developer\r"
interact
```

**Error**: ssh: connect to host t002 port 22: Connection refused

This is the way I'm currently logging in manually from home successfully:

```
~/Desktop # ssh host
```

prompt to enter password.

Once logged on successfully.

```
-bash-4.2$ ssh user@t002
```

prompt to enter password again.

**EDIT:** I updated the second ssh line as suggested by Mike.

From:

```
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $login@$addr2 -p 22
```

To:

`send "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $login@$addr2 -p 22\r"`

Now the script returns access denied, but at the same time it does log me into the server but not the virtual machine.

Comment: If you need to go through a "jumpbox" to get to the server you're really interested in, OpenSSH supports that without needing to write your own scripts. Check out options ProxyCommand (old version of OpenSSH) or ProxyJump (the new way to do it). Using ssh config files, you can easily set it up so that all you have to do is type `ssh t001` on your box at home and you will automatically hop through the jumpbox to the VM.

Comment: Hi Cryptarch, is there a guide that you could perhaps direct me to? Cheers

Comment: is the difference between the `t001` host in the manual method and the `t002` in the `expect` script just a typo? If yes, it would help if you cut and pasted the exact scripts and commands you were using instead of retyping them.

Comment: Hi Mosvy, its just a typo. Now updated. They are the exact commands im using except the credentials.

Comment: try getting rid of the `-p 22` in the `send "ssh...` command.

Comment: @user2023: The main reference is the ssh_config manual: `man ssh_config`. An example introductory walkthrough to setting up an ssh config is https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/ (I'll create an Answer so I can target exactly what you want to do.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to unix.stackexchange.com. Please do not forget to mark your accepted answer with a green check mark if you find it useful and you feel that it meets the quality standards of the forum. Your chosen answer may be the one with the more upvotes or not. It's up to you. The check mark is located left of the answer below the karma point counter. You'll need to login to have access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common problem that you want to get to a server which is not directly accessible from the external internet, but it *is* accessible from a publicly exposed intermediate host. (The intermediate host is called a *jumpbox*.)

Since this problem is so common, it is natural that OpenSSH would provide convenience methods that simplify working with jumpboxes (or jumpboxen?). There are two ways, an old way and a new way. The old way still works, but the new way is more intuitive and makes fewer assumptions about what applications are available on the jumpbox.

Using the example machines mentioned in the question, it can be done like so:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyJump=myuser@test.ac.uk myuser@t002
```

Or, rather than `-o ProxyJump=myuser@test.ac.uk`, I think `-W myuser@test.ac.uk` is equivalent.

Either way, that method requires a new enough version of OpenSSH. If you get stuck with an old version, you need to do something like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand='ssh myuser@test.ac.uk "nc %h %p"' myuser@t002
```

The old way assumes you have netcat installed on the jumpbox.

Another benefit of the new way is you don't need to keep a private key on the jumpbox. ProxyJump is clever enough to try using the private key you have locally. So, if the jumpbox is compromised, it need not be able to compromise anything behind the jumpbox.

Now, you might get sick of writing out that big long command every time. The more you use ssh, the more incentive you will have to set up an `$HOME/.ssh/config`. That is a file where you can give aliases to remote hosts, and associate particular configurations with those hosts.

For your example, an ssh_config would be set up like so:

```
Host jumpbox
User myuser
Hostname test.ac.uk
StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Host t002
User myuser
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
ProxyJump jumpbox
```

With that configuration in place, you should now be able to log into t002 using a much simpler command:

```
ssh t002
```

There is a lot of other cool stuff you can do with an ssh_config. Have a look through `man ssh_config` and revisit it every now and then as you learn more about ssh. You'll keep finding more cool things you can do :)

An example introductory walkthrough to setting up an ssh config is https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/

Comment: Hi Cryptarch, I prefer the ssh_config file method. I have configured it and it works. Is there a way to hard code the password so that I don't have to enter it twice?

Comment: Hi @user2023 The more convenient *and* more secure way to authenticate with ssh is to use keypairs. Use `ssh-keygen` to generate a pair of keys, one private and one public. You put the public half on any server you want to log into. When you generate the keys, you can choose a passphrase for the private key. You can leave the passphrase empty if you like. If you do choose a passphrase, you can use `ssh-agent` to remember the passphrase for you, so you don't need to keep typing it. A basic walkthrough is at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: Cheers Cryptarch I will try that. Thank you to everyone else for their assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a command in a script to reduce typing, and type the user creds!

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@test.ac.uk 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@t002'
```

Tailor to your needs..

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@test.ac.uk 'ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@t002'
```

Copy the key from the 1st server to your pc and referance it like so:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@test.ac.uk 'ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /ssh/1stserverkey myuser@t002'
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I appreciate your response. When I run that command it returns errors: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: O i see, The pseudo-terminal is complaining because of the input not comming directly from a local terminal. Hmmm...

Comment: I have a similar setup at home, some vitualboxs' running on my server and I do work on them from my laptop. I just type everything out. I will try to get this working myself if I find the solution I will post it..

Comment: I look forward to your response.

Comment: Now all I need is to find out a way to get the public key to unlock remotely. @user2023

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec: (1) Please don't put stuff like that into comments; you can see how it turns out.  I'm not sure why you're posting a bunch of debug messages, but if they're relevant to your answer, they should probably be an [edit] to your answer.  (2) Isn't it necessary to pass the `-tt` option to the *first* (outer) `ssh` command?

Answer (score 1):

You spawn a new ssh. Try:

```
send "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $login@$addr2 -p 22\r"
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I just tried your suggestion, it returns permission denied. Though it does log me in to the server but not the virtual machine.